# X-axis Plot with Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

The code is running ok but on the `X axis` the date is not showen compelety as it described in the dictionary(it shows on the plot just `hours:minute:second`).

how can I show the complete date (`year:month:day hours:minute:second`)?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

EQ = {'2017-08-23 02:04:00':(18,1),'2017-08-23 02:05:00':(20,2),'2017-08-23 02:06:00':(12,3),'2017-08-23 02:07:00':(22,4)}
LIST_P=[];Time_P=[]
for j_p in EQ.keys():
        LIST_P.append(EQ[j_p][1])
        Time_P.append(time.mktime(time.strptime(j_p, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))

dateconv=np.vectorize(datetime.fromtimestamp)
Date_F1=dateconv(Time_P)
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = plt.gca()
ax1.plot_date(Date_F1,LIST_P,'g-')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y-axis',fontsize=14)
ax1.set_xlabel('X-axis',fontsize=14)
ax1.grid(True)
for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(45)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))` to specify the format. 
Consider below code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

EQ = {'2017-08-23 02:04:00':(18,1),'2017-08-23 02:05:00':(20,2),'2017-08-23 02:06:00':(12,3),'2017-08-23 02:07:00':(22,4)}
LIST_P=[];Time_P=[]
for j_p in EQ.keys():
        LIST_P.append(EQ[j_p][1])
        Time_P.append(time.mktime(time.strptime(j_p, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))

dateconv=np.vectorize(datetime.fromtimestamp)
Date_F1=dateconv(Time_P)
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = plt.gca()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
ax1.plot_date(Date_F1,LIST_P,'g-')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y-axis',fontsize=14)
ax1.set_xlabel('X-axis',fontsize=14)
ax1.grid(True)
for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(45)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use DateFormatter of matplotlib.dates, adding the following:

1) In the beginning:
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

2) Before ax1.plot_date:
myFmt = DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)